# Hacer que las preguntas no se repitan en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

colegas, espero se encuentren bien. Estoy intentando mostrar unas preguntas con su respectiva opción de respuesta, pero tengo un inconveniente porque quiero que solamente se muestre las preguntas que no han sido contestadas y no he podido.

Esta es la tabla la cual se va guardando las preguntas contestadas
[image]

Esta es la tabla donde esta el enunciado de la pregunta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que al momento en que yo conteste la pregunta se guarde en la tabla de calificación pero que no se repita. He intentado hacerlo con los códigos que están aca debajo pero no me ha funcionado ya que, si se guardan, pero se sigue repitiendo o si no se repite da error

Este es la estructura de la bd
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el Código que tengo en la vista

```
    <?php if ($errores): ?>
        <div class="error">
            <?php echo $errores; ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div class="contenedor">
        <h2 class="contenedor__Pregunta">Pregunta <?php echo $resultadoPregunta[0]['id'] ?></h2>
        <div class="contenedor__Opciones">
            <h3 class="contenedor__parrafo"><?php echo $resultadoPregunta[0]['enunciado_pregunta'] . '<br>'; ?></h3> <!-- Mostrar la pregunta -->
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" name="preguntas">
              <?php
    
              //Recorre las respuestas de acuerdo a la pregunta
              foreach ($resultadoRespuestas as $fila) {
                  echo '<p><label>
                  <input class="with-gap" type="radio" name="respuesta" value="' . $fila['validacion_pregunta_id'] . '"/>
                  <span>' . $fila['contenido_respuestas'] . '<br>' .'</span>
                  </label> </p>';
              }
              ?>
    
    
              <!-- Boton de enviar los datos -->
              <div class="col s10 offset-s1 center-align">
                <i class="#7986cb indigo lighten-2 btn" onclick="preguntas.submit()">Enviar datos</i>
              </div>
            </form>
    
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Estas son las modificaciones que realize en la logica

```
    //Mostrar las preguntas
    $sqlPreguntas =$conexion->prepare('SELECT p.* FROM preguntas_introduccion p JOIN usuarios u LEFT JOIN calificacion c ON c.preguntas_introduccion_id = p.id AND c.usuarios_id = u.id WHERE u.id = :idUsuario AND c.id is null ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1');
    $sqlPreguntas->execute(array(':idUsuario' => $idUsuario));
    $resultadoPregunta = $sqlPreguntas->fetchAll();
    //id de la pregunta
    $idPregunta = isset($resultadoPregunta[0]['id']) ? $resultadoPregunta[0]['id'] : null;
    
    //Si no hay preguntas
    if ($resultadoPregunta == false) {
        $errores .= '<script>alert("Felicidades! Has terminado el test");</script>';
        header('Refresh: 0.1 ; URL=calificacionIntroduccion.php');
    }
    
    //Mostrar las respuestas
    if ($resultadoPregunta != false) {
        $sqlRespuestas = $conexion->prepare('SELECT r.* FROM opcion_respuesta_introduccion r JOIN preguntas_introduccion p ON r.preguntas_introduccion_id = p.id WHERE p.id = :idPregunta');
        $sqlRespuestas->execute(array(':idPregunta' => $resultadoPregunta[0]['id']));
        $resultadoRespuestas = $sqlRespuestas->fetchAll();
    }
```

Y este es el codigo de insertar cada pregunta

```
    // Recibimos los datos del formulario
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $respuesta = $_POST['respuesta'];
        
        $sql_calificacion = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO calificacion (id, usuarios_id, preguntas_introduccion_id, validacion_pregunta_id) VALUES (NULL, :usuarios_id, :preguntas_introduccion_id, :validacion_pregunta_id)');
        $sql_calificacion->execute(array(':usuarios_id' => $idUsuario,':preguntas_introduccion_id' => $idPregunta,':validacion_pregunta_id' => $respuesta));
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿De qué modo determinas las preguntas que no han sido contestadas?

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy haciendo la comparación entre tablas es decir hago un select donde me muestra los datos que aún no se encuentra en la otra tabla. Son dos select. No se si lo esté haciendo bien

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un solo `SELECT`, pero si no explicas cómo están estructuradas las tablas y cómo se decide las preguntas no contestadas, es complicado poder ayudarte. Este tema va más de diseño de tablas que de el mismo código PHP. Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo tienes organizadas las tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo intente hacerlo con un solo select usando una variable random que me genere del 1 al 5 pero se me ha sido imposible hacer que no se repitan las preguntas. Ya edite el post y muestro bien la base de datos

Comment: Prueba con esta consulta: `SELECT p.* FROM preguntas_introduccion p JOIN usuarios u LEFT JOIN calificacion c ON c.preguntas_introduccion_id = p.id AND c.usuarios_id = u.id WHERE u.id = :idUsuario AND c.id is null ORDER BY rand()`.